# mvn --resume-from downloads snapshots

Tags: maven

I have a multi-module maven project with 5 modules. The modules are tiered such that a few depend on the first that builds (it's my model classes) and some depend on the second ones that build (those are core application classes). The final one that builds is a Spring WebMVC app which depends on all the other modules.

The problem I'm having is in Maven's `--resume-from` flag. It apparently doesn't do what I want. I must me misunderstanding what the word "resume" means in this context as I would expect it to, well, *resume something*.

If I run `mvn verify` and it fails at the rest-api sub-module, it tells me I can resume by running `mvn --resume-from :rest-api verify`. When I do that though, it downloads *snapshots* of the other modules from my project which rest-api depends on. That is so incredibly *not* what I want that it's comical. I wanted it to re-use the in-place jars it just built like 5 seconds ago inside this local checkout of the project!

Does anyone know what the nature of my misunderstanding is here? Am I misusing inter-module dependencies? Am I totally misunderstanding what `--resume-from` means? Is there some other argument to do what I want?

Comment: What exactly does the message says? Can you paste the message output here?

Comment: There's no specific message, the command is valid. It just doesn't do what I think it should do. It "resumes" from the specified module, but for anything that was before that module in the build sequence it downloads the latest SNAPSHOT instead of using the version from the submodule's target directory.

Answer (score -1):

Use `mvn install` instead of `mvn verify`, as only after the `install` phase, Maven will be able to pull it from your local repo.

You probably also want the `--also-make-dependents` option.

See [this blog](http://blog.sonatype.com/2009/10/maven-tips-and-tricks-advanced-reactor-options/) for the full story.

Comment: The problem isn't that I need to build something that it otherwise wouldn't have, the problem is that I _don't_ want it to build something it already did. Say I have a project with two maven modules. I run "mvn verify" and one project built and passed tests, then the second one fails some tests. When I run "mvn verify -rf second-module" I don't want it to re-build and re-test the first module, I already know that one works. The problem is that Maven doesn't know to use the jar that was built by the last successful local build for the first module - it downloads a snapshot instead.

Comment: @Martin: Ah, okay... then I guess you'd rather use `mvn install` instead of `mvn verify`. Only after the `install` phase, Maven will be able to pull it from your local repo. Changed my answer accordingly.